# Is it possible to do a break-word but not wrap whitespaces using only CSS and not HTML symbols like &nbsp;?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to do a break-word but not wrap whitespaces using only CSS and not using any HTML symbols like `&nbsp;`?

Desired output (break the "word" at the width of the div, don't break line in white spaces):

```
<div class="click_to_copy">Basic SWtTQk5zNThZM1EbERCcUlTQUQ5clET1dPU3
VORHFzT1kQnNheWFMR25CVncVDQyYkp1c0dkVTQMUJnc0xnV1ZEN3MTGYvNmVyOEJiMmM
MkkrQ1hEWkFaZjAL0hjMnZxbWpuNHcNzVGWG9MbFF6Z28RkNZbC9wdmo0TUEenNXSGpjR
VkzZ00aG9wYURMZElvR0Ua1FPajhZb0hKSk0cm51RjZHQVRub2sS1JNOE5VUStUSlUVVI
xcCtzUkxjSncY</div>
```

Undesirable output #1 (no breaks anywhere):

```
<div class="click_to_copy">Basic SWtTQk5zNThZM1EbERCcUlTQUQ5clET1dPU3VORHFzT1kQnNheWFMR25CVncVDQyYkp1c0dkVTQMUJnc0xnV1ZEN3MTGYvNmVyOEJiMmMMkkrQ1hEWkFaZjAL0hjMnZxbWpuNHcNzVGWG9MbFF6Z28RkNZbC9wdmo0TUEenNXSGpjRVkzZ00aG9wYURMZElvR0Ua1FPajhZb0hKSk0cm51RjZHQVRub2sS1JNOE5VUStUSlUVVIxcCtzUkxjSncY</div>
```

Undesirable output #2 (breaking the word and whitespaces):

```
<div class="click_to_copy">Basic
SWtTQk5zNThZM1EbERCcUlTQUQ5clET1dPU3VORHFzT1kQnNheWFMR25CVncVDQyYkp1c
0dkVTQMUJnc0xnV1ZEN3MTGYvNmVyOEJiMmMMkkrQ1hEWkFaZjAL0hjMnZxbWpuNHcNzV
GWG9MbFF6Z28RkNZbC9wdmo0TUEenNXSGpjRVkzZ00aG9wYURMZElvR0Ua1FPajhZb0hK
Sk0cm51RjZHQVRub2sS1JNOE5VUStUSlUVVIxcCtzUkxjSncY</div>
```

Visually, I got it to work by making it `Basic&nsp;SWtTQk5zNThZM1...` and using `overflow-wrap: break-word;` but the purpose is to display the Basic auth key and copy it to the clipboard.

Note: This example is not a real Basic auth key, its just a random string to represent the value.

So far I've tried different combinations of one or more of these:

```
.nowrap{white-space:nowrap;}
.pre-line{white-space:pre-line;}
.breakword{overflow-wrap: break-word;}
.word-break-all{word-break: break-all;}
.ofw-anywhere{overflow-wrap: anywhere;}
.justify-start{justify-content: start}
```

Comment: How about using the [pre tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre)?

Comment: Post a proper [reprex], so people can investigate the issue...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if I understand you correctly, but `word-break: break-all;`  does what you describe:

```css
.click_to_copy {
  word-break: break-all; 
}
```

```html
<div class="click_to_copy">Basic SWtTQk5zNThZM1EbERCcUlTQUQ5clET1dPU3VORHFzT1kQnNheWFMR25CVncVDQyYkp1c0dkVTQMUJnc0xnV1ZEN3MTGYvNmVyOEJiMmMMkkrQ1hEWkFaZjAL0hjMnZxbWpuNHcNzVGWG9MbFF6Z28RkNZbC9wdmo0TUEenNXSGpjRVkzZ00aG9wYURMZElvR0Ua1FPajhZb0hKSk0cm51RjZHQVRub2sS1JNOE5VUStUSlUVVIxcCtzUkxjSncY</div>
```

Comment: I was sure that I had tried that and it didn't work. lol Just tried again and it did work as I asked. Thanks!